# How to display results of for loop in jtextarea? Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to display all the results of my tweet from a for loop into jtextarea. And display each in a row.

Please check my code fyi:

```
try {

        ResponseList<Status> a = twitter.getUserTimeline(new Paging(1,20));

        for(Status b: a) {
            System.out.println(b.getText());
            textArea.setText(b.getText());

        }

    }catch(Exception e ){

    }
```

I know it has something to do with

```
  textArea.setText(b.getText());
```

Sorry I'm new to Java so I still need help. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: @Philipp I've updated my post. I want to display each in a row. What just happens it displays the last result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setText` replaces the components text content. [append](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29) appends the given text to the end of the document:

```
textArea.append(b.getText());
```

or use

```
textArea.append(b.getText() + "\n");
```

if no terminating newline character are returned from `b.getText()`.

Comment: +1 for the append. However, don't use the system property for a newline. Just use "\n". The Document only stores "\n" in the Document anyway. See [Text and New Lines](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for more detail.

Comment: Yeah thought I was overcooking that a bit, thanks for the link